# How extract values in a lists, generated by loops

Tags: r, loops, desctools

I have to extract p.values of a seven t2 hottelling test generated by loop
this data were generated by computer, changing the correlation.  I need extract the all pvalues for make a plot.

```
i=numeric(0)
p1=numeric(0)
pv=numeric(0)
  for(i in 3:9){
    r=cbind(c(1,(i/10),0.1), c((i/10),1,0.2),c(0.1,0.2,1))
    library(MASS)
    muho=c(55,3.5,7.5)
    data=mvrnorm(100,mu=c(55,3.5,7.5),Sigma = r)
    library(DescTools)
    p1=(HotellingsT2Test(data,mu=muho))
```

Comment: So what is happening (or not happening) when you run this code?

Comment: You can wrap the calculations in `lapply` and use `do.call` for aggregation e.g. `do.call(rbind,lapply(3:9, function(x) { r=cbind; ... ; pValDat = data.frame(xVal = x , pValue=(HotellingsT2Test(data,mu=muho) ) ) } ))` and move `library` calls outside function body